# Read video from OpenCV stream with Unity3D

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, unity-game-engine, streaming

I'm streaming a camera video from another computer, using OpenCV in C++, with VideoCapture.
[Here's the kind of result I get when I read it on my browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJvYL.png)

I can read and display the video with a C++ client on another computer, but I now want to do that with Unity3D.

I already tried the VideoPlayer with URL, it seems that it doesn't work with streaming. 
I also tried to read the URL with WWW and load texture with WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture :

```
IEnumerator Start()
    {
        Texture2D tex;
        tex = new Texture2D(4, 4, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
        WWW www = new WWW("192.168.43.153:5000");
        yield return www;
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);
}
```

But it doesn't work too, I guess it can't do that with a continuous stream.

I don't know if I have to change the streaming in my OpenCV program, or if I can read and display directly from Unity.

Comment: [`DownloadHandlerScript`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandlerScript.html) should be used for as you can use to download data for long time. It reuses the byte array you pass to it to store received data. Something `WWW` cannot do. This is just minor part of this. You also need to write code that extracts the JPEG  from the byte array. See duplicate for more info.

Comment: It looks like there is no JPEG in the string, it looks like OpenCV is streaming a cv::mat, maybe it's not the same as the camera reading you're talking about in the duplicate.
At least I don't find any  `0xFF` followed by `0xD8` marking the JPEG start.

Comment: There is no string or JPEG When I said JPEG, I meant image format. You construct an Texture2D from the JPEG image you received from the server. In order to get that JPEG image, you have to search for 0xFF  like I mentioned in the duplicate. See [this](https://github.com/theta360developers/ThetaWifiStreaming) post which completely shows how to extract the JPEG frame

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant. I read every bytes looking for 0xFF to find the JPEG header, but I really didn't find any. That's why I think there is no JPEG to get in the bytes sent by my OpenCV program. I'll dig the new post you sent, thank you!

Comment: I though you are streaming directly from a network camera not from an OpenCV....Which one?